# where does the Linode server hostname come from?

Tags: server

The default hostname of a [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) cloud virtual server image of Ubuntu 16.04 is "localhost".  This seems a poor choice for a default for a machine that is in the cloud. Was this default determined by Canonical or by Linode?
[image]

Comment: I think linode would be responsible for that.

Comment: Please paste the terminal text as text into your question and apply code formatting. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals

Comment: It's probably in /etc/hosts, and since you have nothing in /etc/hostname it takes the name which it finds in hosts - which bei default is localhost 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked out [the Ubuntu Server 16.04 cloud image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/), and:

```
$ tar Jxf xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz etc/hostname -O
ubuntu
```

If the hostname is `localhost`, the choice was made by Linode.

Answer (score 5):

> This seems a poor choice for a default for a machine that is in the cloud.

No, it is really not a poor choice. "localhost" used from the outside can not do harm. And this forces you to set your own hostname if you want to start using this for something.

Oh and you are the one that did this. See the [Linode manual](https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started#setting-the-hostname): you forgot to do a part of the installation and that is to set a hostname; when that is not set it defaults to "localhost".

> ### Setting the Hostname
>
> You’ll need to set your system’s hostname and fully qualified domain
>   name (FQDN). Your hostname should be something unique. Some people
>   name their servers after planets, philosophers, or animals. Note that
>   the system’s hostname has no relationship to websites or email
>   services hosted on it, aside from providing a name for the system
>   itself. Your hostname should not be “www” or anything too generic.
>
> Once you’re done, you can verify by running the command hostname.
>
> > #### Note
> >
> > If you’re unfamiliar with Linux, one of the first things you’ll need
> >     to learn is how to use nano, a text editor included with most
> >     distributions. To open a file for editing, type nano file.txt where
> >     “file.txt” is the name of the file you want to create or edit. If the
> >     file is not in your current working directory, specify the entire file
> >     path. For example, open the hosts file with:
> >
> > ```
> >   nano /etc/hosts
> > ```
> >
> > When you’re finished editing, press <kbd>Control-X</kbd>, then
> >     <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the changes and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.
>
> #### Arch/CentOS 7/Debian 8/Fedora version 18 and above/ Ubuntu 15.04 and above
>
> Use "hostnamectl" and replace {hostname} with what you want it to be:
>
> ```
>  hostnamectl set-hostname {hostname}
> ```

Comment: A generic hostname such as "linode" or "ubuntu" is superior because it for some people that would be satisfactory. Calling it "localhost" is confusing and almost forces the user to rename it which might be a waste of time. A generic thing should appear to be generic.